# how to assign a value to a parameter in an ifelse block of batch script

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

this code fails in the if else block the parameter cant be assigned a value..
can any body suggest what might be the error? thanks in advance..

```
D:
cd DATA_FILEs\IN

set file="employee_detail.dat"


set /a size=0
set /a maxbytesize=500

FOR %A IN (%file%) DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% LSS %maxbytesize% (
    set errno=0
) ELSE (
   set errno=0
)


EXIT /B %errno%
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

if %size% LSS %maxbytesize% (**set errno=0** ) ELSE (**set errno=0**)

Maybe, just maybe you'd see a difference if you were to set `errno` to different values.